# RGBW 4 channel LED strips: Do I need externalpower supply or is the LED controller enough?

Tags: power, led, controller, strip

Not a beginner but still a novice :)

Main goal is to find out if the LED controllers I have chosen can drive my LED strips or if I need external power supply. And to understand ofcourse :)

Equipment first:
Controller Milight LS2 USD 10 each, buying 8 of them
Voltage: DC12V/24V, Output: Max. 6A/Channel, Total output Max.15A

LED strips
USD 10 each. Aliexpres so no data sheets... 5 pin RGBW 60 chips per m. RGB+W integrated in each chip, analogue I suppose. Miss Ali says about 0.2W per chip = 60 W per 5 meters but I thought most strips were 72 W???

Q: I thought that RGBW would use more power since it has white too?? No?

Q: I thought that amps were constant so is RGBW less bright than RGB per colour? What about total lumens?

Now, can one LS2 controller drive one 5 meter strip? 
Strip lengths: Mostly 4-5 meters, some up to 10 meters.
Please correct me:

1) I understand that channel is red, green, blue and white. Is that correct?

2) Plain green and I get 60W green, mix 2 colurs and I get 30 each? Is this correct?

3) I understand it as one LS2 controller can drive one LED strip up to 5 meter long and I would only need an external power supply if I make a longer than that, say a 10 meter strip => connect up in serial (same zone). Is this correct?

How long can I pull a 1 mm? 22 AGW extension wire before it affects performance, just approximate.

Thanks
Michael

Comment: why are you asking technical questions about an unknown device?

Comment: You need a power supply.

Comment: Please distinguish between unit and quantity: amps is a unit of current and lumens is a unit of luminous flux or luminous power: *Q: I thought that **current** is constant so is RGBW less bright than RGB per colour? What about total **luminous power**?*